# Bug fixes in branch

Tags: git

I'm a sole developer with one main development branch, and one or more feature branches.

I'm wondering right now, if I'm actively developing in a feature branch and I discover a bug in the main branch, what would be the best practice. I would assume:

1. I switch back to main dev branch, fix bug, commit.
2. Switch to feature branch, and merge main branch to feature branch.
3. Continue developing on feature branch.

The above seems to be very cumbersome, all the while losing my current place in the feature branch and breaking my train of thought. Is there a better method?

Comment: I think that if you are going to fix the bug then you are going to break your train of thought, no matter what branching strategy you use.   The process you described is the one that I would have thought was the right thing to do...

Comment: I'm developing in XCode right now, so switching branches kinds of "resets" my file explorer which is annoying and aids the "breaking the train of thought"

Comment: Can't you make a separate checkout of the master branch to fix the bug, leaving your development branch intact?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you deploy to production from your master branch and that feature branches are merged back into master once done I would:

Commit whatever work is done on the feature branch, regardless of it builds or not

```
git commit -a -m'saving work to fix bug'
```

Checkout the master branch and fix the bug and commit it

```
git checkout master
code some
git commit -a -m'fixed nasty production bug'
```

Then checkout the feature branch, rebase the changes and continue work

```
git checkout feature
git rebase
git reset --soft HEAD^
```

That last command will move HEAD one commit back but leave all code in the working copy intact, making it possible to resume work on the feature branch. Note that depending on what was fixed on master you might get conflicts when rebasing.

Comment: Could you clarify why you think this is better than the original process that the OP mentioned?   It seems pretty much the same, except that it adds the complication of the rebase.  I haven't got my head around what you are really suggesting there - the commands don't appear to match the commentary?

Comment: I think rebase is _easier_ than merge. They both have the same conflicts just that the DAG is much cleaner and intuitive with rebase. I've also added steps to preserve the current work temporarily in a commit.